# Manipulating Strings in a File Scanner ~ Java

Tags: java, file, substring, delimiter

I was given a file that has list of names phone numbers, calls in and out ect... Like this

```
Adams#Marilyn#8233331109#0#0#01012014#C
Anderson#John#5025559980#20#15#12152013#M
Baker-Brown#Angelica#9021329944#0#3#02112014#C
```

The # are delimiters between data items and each line has the call status as the last item.
I need to know how I can display each persons information on the screen in a format such as:

Name            Phone           Calls Out       Calls In    Last Call

Marilyn Adams       (823) 333-1109      0         0     01-01-2104
John Anderson       (502) 555-9980      20        15        12-15-2013
Angelica Baker-Brown    (859) 254-1109      11         5        02-11-2014

I have to use substring method to extract the phone number and add parentheses/dashes ect...

So Far my code looks like this
Also I am in a beginners Java coding class....

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class phonedata2_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String Phonefile, FirstName, LastName;
        Scanner PhoneScan, fileScan;

        System.out.println("    Name      Phone      Calls Out       Calls In       Last Call           Status");

        fileScan = new Scanner(new File("phonedata.txt"));

        while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
            Phonefile = fileScan.nextLine();

            PhoneScan = new Scanner(Phonefile);
            PhoneScan.useDelimiter("#");

            System.out.println(PhoneScan.next() + " " 
                    + PhoneScan.next() + "\t" 
                    + PhoneScan.next() + "\t"
                    + PhoneScan.next() + "\t" 
                    + PhoneScan.next() + "\t" 
                    + PhoneScan.next() + "\t" 
                    + PhoneScan.next());
        }
        System.out.println("\nTotal outgoing calls for the period: " + "\nTotal incoming calls    for the period: \n");

    }
}
```

Comment: using regex you could filter the whole file's content, getting a multidimensional array with captions included: /((\S*)#){6}(\w)/

Comment: Please mark one answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finds every "data-segment" by using regex, then splits it with # as delimiter and prints it:

```
    File blub = new File("blub.txt");

    Scanner scanner = null;
    try
    {
        scanner = new Scanner(blub);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){}


    while(scanner.hasNext("((\\S*)#){6}(\\w)"))
    {
        String buffer = scanner.next("((\\S*)#){6}(\\w)");
        for(String value : buffer.split("#"))
            System.out.print(value + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Adams Marilyn 8233331109 0 0 01012014 C 
Anderson John 5025559980 20 15 12152013 M 
Baker-Brown Angelica 9021329944 0 3 02112014 C
```

**Note:**
You can use any whitespace character to separate each data-segment in the input file, so even spaces are okay or tabs(or crazy mix with empty lines and so on).

**For farther use of data:**
you could add your data in an arraylist since buffer.split("#") gives you an array of the data-segment, so you can output it easier with your desired changes to each value.(or in a different order)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the line you are reading by throwing in the `#` as a delimeter. This will yield an array which you can traverse and print the contents accordingly. Also, it would seem that besides the initial line, all call data starts with a , so you could use split twice to parse your text file:

EDIT: Seeing your comment, I also realized that afterwards, however, since the `.split()` method takes a regex as parameter, it means that this problem can be walked around without much hassle. My example is as follows:

```
    String str = "Adams#Marilyn#8233331109#0#0#01012014#C Anderson#John#5025559980#20#15#12152013#M Baker-Brown#Angelica#9021329944#0#3#02112014#C";
    String[] lines = str.split(" ");
    System.out.println("Name\tPhone\tCalls\tOut\tCalls In\tLast Call");
    for(String line : lines)
    {
        String[] lineInfo = line.split("#");
        for(String info : lineInfo)
        {
            System.out.print(info + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I had to add some extra tabs manually, but this is the output:

```
Name        Phone       Calls       Out Calls In    Last Call
Adams       Marilyn     8233331109  0   0           01012014    C   
Anderson    John        5025559980  20  15          12152013    M   
Baker-Brown Angelica    9021329944  0   3           02112014    C
```

Comment: In regards to the "#C" thing, I noticed this but I thought it was at the end of the data as then you get "#C", "#M" and "#C" for the different records. The #M threw me a bit because it seems out of place.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the #C and #M are the Status of the calls such as missed. I get the str.split its way easier but I have to ask how do you do it its in a file and you do the split then if you are using:
    new File ("datafile");

Comment: @user3350626: I made some amendments to the answer which should fix your problem. As to regards to reading it from file, then I would recommend you read the entire file using a `StringBuilder` and then, once read, you would operate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You still need to do all the manipulation of the phone number yourself, but all the data will be in the call info so you should be able to work from that!

```
while (fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        //Get a single record
        Phonefile = fileScan.nextLine();

        //Seperate the elements of the record        
        String[] callInfo = Phonefile.split("#");

        for(String infoPart: callInfo)
        {
            System.out.print(infoPart+ "\t");
        }

        System.out.println()
    }
```